# Regular Expression Issue with Start and End Anchors

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression (in Javascript):

```
/^(\d+-\d+){1}(,\d+-\d+)*$/
```

I want it to match the following:

```
100-200
100-200,300-400
34-765,2-7,8-100
```

I do not want it to match this:

```
abc123-500def
```

The start and end characters are causing nothing to get matched.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a link with an example.  No matches.  https://www.regextester.com/?fam=102532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my example spanned multiple lines, it turned out I needed the multi-line flag /gm.

```
/^(\d+-\d+){1}(,\d+-\d+)*$/gm
```

Comment: I think you do not need the `{1}`

Comment: I do want the first group to appear once.  The second group is optional, hence the *.